# how to display xml data in input field using xslt?

Tags: xml, forms, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to bind xml to a form input as the value using xslt.

this is a snippet of my code (xsl):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

    <input name="Supervisor" id="Supervisor" binding="my:myFields/my:Supervisor" ftXPath="my:myFields/my:Supervisor">
       <xsl:value-of select="my:myFields/my:Supervisor"/>
    </input>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<my:myFields xmlns:my="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">

 <my:Supervisor>Jane Doe</my:Supervisor>
</my:myFields>
```

I tried that but I cant seem to get the value to be in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to populate an HTML input control then you need to set its `value` attribute:

`<input value="{my:myFields/my:mySupervisor}" .../>`

Make sure the stylesheet declares the same namespace for the prefix my like the input XML.

Comment: oh thanks, i actually tried that before and it didn't work. now it did . it was probably a syntax error. Thanks again